# i am Trying more Flags to prevent the Activity to be opened more than one time at the Same time

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-pendingintent, mobile-development

i tried Flags  like

```
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

i Login to my application and open the home page > when i receive a notification and preessed on it to see details at home page it opened well But the previous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with the help of launch mode

go to manifest where your activity is declared.
And add following attribute to your activity declaration.

**android:launchMode="singleTask"**

And in your activity class ovveride following method

```
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
   setIntent(intent);
   //do other stuff with new intent
}
```

I will also suggest you to read more about activity launch mode https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html